# How can I programatically close a SPECIFIC java application running in windows from within another program?

Tags: java, windows

I need to (force)close a specific java application from within another program. For any native program killing it's process or sending vm_close to it's main window usually works but not so much with java applications running on windows. Do note that the java application is only showing a tray icon and has no open window during it's normal state.

Answer (score 3):

If you know your Java program's PID, use this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID bla");
```

where `bla` is your program's PID.

That `/F` parameter will forcefully kill an application and I don't see a reason why a Java program would be any different from other programs and be able to survive that.

Note that this code is obviously Windows specific. If you want it to be portable, you should first find out what OS is hosting your application by using

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

and afterwards, use `taskkill /F` if you're on Windows, or `kill -9` if you're on a *nix system, or something else if you're on a more exotic platform.

**Update**: to have a nice overview of all running processes, I'd recommend [Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). If you want a command line process lister, use [PsList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682).

If you want to kill a specific Java program, it can be problematic since every Java process by default is named `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`.

Using PsList, you can programatically scan all processes which start with `java` and then, combined with `jps`, you'll have more information about what you really want to kill.

Comment: It is not my application so I'm not sure if I can get a PID from it, also does it really have one considering javaw.exe is the only process running when the program is running. There could be multiple javaw.exe during multiple java programs but I haven't looked for that. Any suggestion on how to get the PID?

Comment: If you run jps -lvm you can get the full command line of the java programs. You need to know something about the process you want to kill.

Comment: Great the jps tool was what I needed, now that I  have that PID from there it should be piece of cake!

Comment: @Kristian: I've added more methods for you which can assist you in finding the real PID.

Comment: I just realized JPS requires the JDK to be installed on the computer doing this, and that is mostly not the case for client computers, is there any other way?

Comment: @Darioo: I'm trying to find some info on the path of execution etc on the different javaw.exe windows, haven't found anything yet but that's what I'm hoping to do as this wouldn't require any special tools on the client computer.

Comment: The method needed was getting the commandline of the process, that itself is pretty complicated but it does work.

Comment: @Kristian: after you see the list of utilities used, I doubt you can easily identify and kill such a java process without installing at least something on client's computers...

Answer (score 0):

an easy hack is to copy/paste a second version of the java.exe (or javaw.exe), call it java_alt.exe and then kill the process by the new name using Unix Tools for windows

Comment: The java application I need killed isn't mine, I'm killing it from within another program, would this still work then?

Comment: provided you have 'permission' to kill that process and can identify it. Would it be possible to get that process to use an alternately named java executable?

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrote the process ID of the java application to a temp file in a known location. When the program starts up, do something like:

```
//mark the instance file for delete
String instanceFileLocation = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + "instances.dat";
File PIDFile = new File(instanceFileLocation).deleteOnExit();
//write the process id here
```

Then any program or application could find the temp file and specific process id. Use the other solutions posted to kill it.

Then use

Comment: it's not my own application so this is not an option